# Sorting multiple columns by first letter and by numbers in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have created a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
item  mean
a_b   5
a_c   2
a_a   4
b_d   7
b_f   3
b_e   1
```

I would like to sort it so that it is first sorted by whether or not it begins with "a_" or "b_", and then have it sorted by mean. The final dataframe should look like this:

```
item  mean
a_c   2
a_a   4
a_b   5
b_e   1
b_f   3
b_d   7
```

Note that the item column is not sorted perfectly alphabetically. It is only sorted by the first letter.

I have tried:

```
arrange(df, item, mean)
```

The problem with this is that it does not only sort by the "a_" and "b_" categories, but by the entire item name.

I am open to separating the original dataframe into separate dataframes using filter and then sorting the mean within these smaller subsets. I do not need everything to stay in the same dataframe. However, I am unsure how to use filter to only select rows that have items beginning with "a_" or "b_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(df, sub('_.+$', '', item), mean)
```

an alternative would be to use `str_extract` from `stringr` to extract only the first letter from `item`:

```
library(stringr)
arrange(df, str_extract(item, '^._'), mean)
```

**Result:**

```
  item mean
1  a_c    2
2  a_a    4
3  a_b    5
4  b_e    1
5  b_f    3
6  b_d    7
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(item = c("a_b", "a_c", "a_a", "b_d", "b_f", "b_e"
), mean = c(5L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("item", "mean"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**Notes:**

- `sub('_.+$', '', item)` creates a temporary variable by **removing** `_` and everything after that from `item`. `_.+$` matches a literal underscore (`_`) followed by any character one or more times (`.+`) at the end of the string (`$`).
- `str_extract(item, '^._')` creates a temporary variable by **extracting** any one character (`.`) followed by a literal underscore (`_`) in the beginning of the string (`^`)
- The neat thing about `dplyr::arrange` is that you can create a temporary sorting variable within the function and not have it included in the output.

Comment: This seems to alphabetize the mean column first by looking at the entire item names, not just the first letter. When I run it, a_a, a_b, and a_c are in order, which is not what I want.

Comment: @melbez with the same sample output you provided? The **Result** is what I got when I run the code.

Comment: Could you please explain what this part means: sub('_.$', '', item)

Comment: @melbez It uses a regular expression to create a temporary variable that removes "\_" and everything after it in `item`, which would be the first letter of `item`. `arrange` when sorts by that temporary variable _and_ `mean`.

Comment: Ok, the only difference between the df I provided in the example and the one in my actual data is that in the actual data some of the item names are things like a_apple, a_banana, a_corn instead of a_a, a_b, and a_c. It seems like the code you wrote should still work, right?

Comment: @melbez no, in this case it wouldn't, because `.` only matches once. You can easily change it to match an arbitrary number of characters by adding a `+`. See my edits

Answer (score 1):

The philosophy is that if you want to `arrange` by something (i.e. a substring here) you have to obtain it first:

```
df = read.table(text = "
item  mean
a_b   5
a_c   2
a_a   4
b_d   7
b_f   3
b_e   1
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(item, c("item1","item2"), remove = F) %>% # split items while keeping the original column
  arrange(item1, mean) %>%                           # arrange by what you really want
  select(item, mean)                                 # keep only relevant columns

#   item mean
# 1  a_c    2
# 2  a_a    4
# 3  a_b    5
# 4  b_e    1
# 5  b_f    3
# 6  b_d    7
```

Note that there are various ways to pick the 1st letter from a string. I just decided to use `separate` here.

In case you have many items separated by `_` you'll still need to extract the first item, so you can replace the first `_` with another delimiter (let's say `:`) and separate your column on that:

```
df = read.table(text = "
item  mean
a_b_m   5
a_c   2
a_a   4
b_d_x_q   7
b_f   3
b_e   1
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(item2 = str_replace(item, "_", ":")) %>%
  separate(item2, c("item1","item2"), remove = F, sep = ":") %>% 
  arrange(item1, mean) %>%                           
  select(item, mean) 

#      item mean
# 1     a_c    2
# 2     a_a    4
# 3   a_b_m    5
# 4     b_e    1
# 5     b_f    3
# 6 b_d_x_q    7
```

Comment: How can I modify this so that it works if I have over 200 items? I do not want to write c("item1", "item2", etc) for over 200 items.

Comment: Depends. Are they all separated by `_`? You can separate by the first `_` and give the names "item1" and "rest items". Based on your example I couldn't imagine you could have that many items. :) I thought to use separate in case you want to order by the second item (i.e. letter)

Comment: Yes, all the items are separated by an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution would be

```
inx <- order(substr(df$item, 1, 1), df$mean)
newdf <- df[inx, ]

newdf
#  item mean
#2  a_c    2
#3  a_a    4
#1  a_b    5
#6  b_e    1
#5  b_f    3
#4  b_d    7
```